# Regex to match all combinations of a given string

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I am trying to make a regex to matches all the combinations of a given string. For example of the string is "1234", answers would include:

1. "1"
2. "123"
3. "4321"
4. "4312"

Nonexamples would include:

1. "11"
2. "11234"
3. "44132"

If it matters, the programming language I am using is javascript.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Regex is likely the wrong way to accomplish whatever you're trying to do with that.

Comment: What is a good way to accomplish this?

Comment: Sort your candidate and compare to the original (assuming that the original is already sorted like in your example).

Comment: I see you're doing a simple `[1-4]+`

Comment: @VishnuMurthy Did any of the responses answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use regex for this. The snippet below does the following:

1. Loop over possible combinations (`a => s`) (`1`, `123`, `4321`, etc.)
2. Copy the current combination so as not to overwrite it (`s2 = s`)
3. Loop over the characters of test string (`x => ch`) (`1234` => `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`)
4. Replace common characters in the combination string shared with the test string (`s2.replace`)

   - For example in the combination `1`, the `1` will be replaced when the loop gets to the character `1` in `1234` resulting in an empty string
5. If the combination string's length reaches `0` (`s2.length == 0`) write the result to the console and break out of the loop (no point in continuing to attempt to replace on an empty string)

```js
const x = "1234"
const a = ["1","123","4321","4312","11","11234","44132"]

a.forEach(function(s) {
  var s2 = s
  for(var ch of x) {
    s2 = s2.replace(ch, '')
    if(s2.length == 0) {
      console.log(s);
      break;
    }
  }
})
```

Results:

```
1
123
4321
4312
```

Answer (score 4):

You may use this lookahead based assertions in your regex:

```
^(?!(?:[^1]*1){2})(?!(?:[^2]*2){2})(?!(?:[^3]*3){2})(?!(?:[^4]*4){2})[1234]+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DJwJ6s/1)

Here we have 4 lookahead assertions:

- `(?!(?:[^1]*1){2})`: Assert that we don't have more than one instance of `1`
- `(?!(?:[^2]*2){2})`: Assert that we don't have more than one instance of `2`
- `(?!(?:[^3]*3){2})`: Assert that we don't have more than one instance of `3`
- `(?!(?:[^4]*4){2})`: Assert that we don't have more than one instance of `4`

We use `[1234]+` to match any string with these 4 characters.

Answer (score 2):

A combination of group captures using character classes and negative look-ahead assertions using back-references would do the trick.

Let's begin with simply matching any combination of 1, 2, 3, and 4 using a character class,`[1-4]`, and allowing any length from 1 to 4 characters. `{1,4}`.

```js
const regex = /^[1-4]{1,4}$/;

// Create set of inputs from 0 to 4322
const inputs = Array.from(new Array(4323), (v, i) => i.toString());

// Output only values that match criteria
console.log(inputs.filter((input) => regex.test(input)));
```

When that code is run, it's easy to see that although only numbers consisting of some combination of 1, 2, 3, and 4 are matched, it also is matching numbers with repeating combinations (e.g. 11, 22, 33, 112, etc). Obviously, this was not what was desired.

To prevent repeating characters requires a reference to previously matched characters and then a negation of them from any following matched characters. Negative look-aheads, `(?!...)` using a back-reference, `\1-9`, can accomplish this.

Building on the previous example with a subset of the inputs (limiting to a max length of two characters for the moment) would now incorporate a group match surrounding the first character, `([1-4])`, followed by a negative look-ahead with a back-reference to the first capture, `(?!\1)`, and finally a second optional character class.

```js
const regex = /^([1-4])(?!\1)[1-4]?$/;

// Create set of inputs from 0 to 44
const inputs = Array.from(new Array(45), (v, i) => i.toString());

// Output only values that match criteria
console.log(inputs.filter((input) => regex.test(input)));
```

This matches the desired characters with no repetition!

Expanding this pattern to include back-references for each of the previously matched characters up to the desired max length of 4 yields the following expression.

```js
const regex = /^([1-4])((?!\1)[1-4])?((?!\1|\2)[1-4])?((?!\1|\2|\3)[1-4])?$/;

// Create set of inputs from 0 to 4322
const inputs = Array.from(new Array(4323), (v, i) => i.toString());

// Output only values that match criteria
console.log(inputs.filter((input) => regex.test(input)));
```

Hope this helps!